# How to check if nothing has been added to an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference

I am new to Java and I have a small program where I have an array of objects:

```
Fruit[] fruit = new Fruit[20];
String fruitName;
int fruitCount = 0;
```

The program looks like this:

```
Select an option:
A. Add a fruit
B. View fruits
```

So, if the user selects option A, a new object is added to the array with the fruitName as parameter. (*Note there is a while loop that keeps asking the user to select a menu option so if every time they select option A, a new object is added to the array. I just haven't added for simplicity*).

```
System.out.println("What fruit? ");
fruitName = scanner.nextLine();

fruit[fruitCount] = new Fruit(fruitName);
fruitCount++;
```

If user wants to select option B view fruits, the array is searched like so and the names of all the fruits are printed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(fruit[i].fruitName); 
}
```

I want an error message to occur if they want to view fruits but there are no objects added. Is there a way to know if the array does not have any objects? So if the user selected option B without adding any fruits yet, it will say "Error, no fruits in the system".

Answer (score 1):

Check if first object is not null

```
If(fruit[0]  == null) {
  System.out.println(" Fruits are not added ");
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you!..I didn't know it would be this simple

Answer (score 1):

You have a `fruitCount` variable all set up. Check if it is 0; seems trivial.